# How to execute crontab -l via php webpage? Linux Permission

Tags: php, linux, unix, permissions

I was wondering if it is even at all possible to execute an command such as "crontab -l" via webpage? This seems to be an permission issue.

```
$out = shell_exec('crontab -l');
echo '<pre>'.$out.'</pre>';
```

When this is executed via PHP, the value of $out is empty.

Comment: It depends on who administer the web server....

Comment: Please elaborate? The script is part of the webpage exposed to the public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what I ended up doing...

1. I added a a cron job to update a txt file with the outout of crontab -l every minute
   crontab -l > /var/www/html/logs/cronJobs.txt
2. Set the permission of cronJobs.txt
3. Link the cronJobs.txt from the PHP page

Answer (score 0):

From PHP.net :

> It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function.
>   exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is
>   required.

I suggest you use exec so that you can check if the command executed successfully. You should be able to output any data.

Something like:

```
exec('crontab -l 2>&1', $output, $return_code)
if ($return_code !== 0) {
    //Returned Error
    echo implode("\n", $output); // display output
} else {
    //Returned OK
    echo implode("\n", $output); // display output
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot. What does 2>&1 do?

Comment: It will pipe error and standard message output to the normal output. This will make sure you get all message returned by the command

Comment: However, it may still not work since it is probably a permission problem and the apache user won't have access to the crontab list.